# Getting TypeError: App.Router is undefined after building ember.js

Tags: node.js, ember.js, ember-data

Posting here as requested original post can be found [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2623) 
Hello, I would like to build ember.js using Ubuntu 13.
I have cloned the official Github project, cd into the project and as described in the readme file I did:
bundle install
rake dist
no error is shown on screen and as a result I get a directory shown in the image
[image]

I would like to use ember and ember-data, so I include
ember.js
ember-data-deps.js
files in my test project.
The problem is that I am getting a TypeError: App.Router is undefined
I am using this at my client.js file to init ember

this.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
this.route('contributors');
this.route('contributor', {path: '/contributors/:contributor_id'});
});

Am I doing something wrong in the build process?
Should I include some other js files in my project?
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: it would also be useful to get see how your project is setup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The `TypeError: App.Router is undefined` error is because ember.js is not loaded correctly or in the correct order.
- To get `ember-data` (that is separate from `ember.js`) you have to clone this repo (https://github.com/emberjs/data) and follow the build instructions in the readme file, it's straight forward, and once you have the `dist` directory from the ember-data build process get the file `ember-data.js` development version or `ember-data.min.js` for production *(well, production... ember-data is still considered unstable for production environments).*

here is a simple ember project setup using ember-data:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ember app</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    hello world!
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://builds.emberjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/handlebars-1.0.0-rc.3.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://builds.emberjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ember-latest.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://builds.emberjs.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ember-data-latest.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({
  ready: function () {
    console.log("app started...");
  }
});
```

hope it helps